# LINQ <Where> with conditional in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to use LINQ WHERE with conditional boolean and skip if false. Example of my code are like this:-

```
var filters = ListResponse.filter.Where(a => a.FLRefID == EvtID).ToList();
foreach(var tofilter in filters)
{
    if (tofilter == null)
        continue;
    // The value in tofilter can be empty
    bool bFilterID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLEventID);
    bool bFilterText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLText);
    bool bFilterSource = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLSource);
    bool bFilterLevel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLLevel);

    // Here in LINQ where I want to filter
    // EventDetails is List of Event Viewer Collection.
    var logs = EventDetails.Where(ax => bFilterID ? (ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID) | bFilterText ? (ax.EventMessage.Contains(tofilter.FLText)) | bFilterSource ? (ax.EventSourceName == tofilter.FLSource) | bFilterLevel ? (ax.Level == tofilter.FLLevel));
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs);
}
```

Let's say USER has selected they want to filter `ID=1, SourceName=Application` and the rest is empty. How do I add the conditional in LINQ if `bFilterID = true` then the `ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID` will be use. If False (not set by user), it will skip the conditional. The filter can be dynamic but it must be at least 1 conditional to be set from USER.

I'm actually does not sure what are the keywords regarding what I'm going to search as I don't know if it exist.

**UPDATED:**
I have test answer from Mik and both answer from npo.

```
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.876405 [INFO] Time taken NPO 1: 00:00:00.0705490
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.889374 [INFO] Time taken NPO 2: 00:00:00.0123487
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.903334 [INFO] Time taken MIK:   00:00:00.0146780
> 
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.947219 [INFO] Time taken NPO 1: 00:00:00.0435493
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.977139 [INFO] Time taken NPO 2: 00:00:00.0297257
> 18-03-2019 10:30:17.981127 [INFO] Time taken MIK:   00:00:00.0036274
> 
> 18-03-2019 10:30:28.536724 [INFO] Time taken NPO 1: 00:00:00.2011405
> 18-03-2019 10:30:28.596560 [INFO] Time taken NPO 2: 00:00:00.0594285
> 18-03-2019 10:30:28.634464 [INFO] Time taken MIK:   00:00:00.0376055
```

Comment: `!bFilterID || ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it:

```
IQueryable<EventDetails> res = EventDetails;

if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLEventID) )
  res = res.Where(ax => ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID); 

if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLText) )
  res = res.Where(ax => ax.EventMessage.Contains(tofilter.FLText));

if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLSource) )
  res = res.Where(ax => ax.EventSourceName == tofilter.FLSource);

if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLLevel) )
  res = res.Where(ax => ax.Level == tofilter.FLLevel);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

It generates multiple subqueries but I don't think there is a perfomance issue, and this is much more readable.

By the way, I inverted your `IsNullOrEmpty` tests, because in your code you are filtering only on empty strings...

Comment: I like the predicate solution from npo too. I has the advantage to generate only one sql WHERE clause, but adds some code complexity.

Comment: I assume you need to invert the if evaluation, it makes no sense to only filter if there is no filter value (this is wrong in OP's question too).

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm saying at the end of my answer. I'll edit to make it right from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

You can write an extension method to conditionally apply the filter:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

And your query becomes:

```
using static System.String;

...

var res = EventDetails
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLEventID), e => e.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID)
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLText), e => tofilter.FLText.Contains(e.FLText))
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLSource), e => e.EventSourceName == tofilter.FLSource)
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLLevel), e => e.Level == tofilter.FLLevel)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: How do you apply the `WhereIf` definition? Currently, when I'm applying it, it shows the error `EventDetails does not contains definition for WhereIf`

Comment: You need to add `using` statement with the namespace of the static class, which implements the extension method.

Comment: I try create a new class and place the extension inside and it show error on the WhereIf. My EventDetails are from `public List<LogDetails> EventDetails { get; set; }` I think I'm doing it in wrong way but I don't know how to determine which part that need to be as working as your propose answer

Comment: The class you created is not visible to the caller. Is the class with the extension method marked as public ?

Comment: Ok, I've just got it. The list that I had need to be in IQueryable type. So after I add `EventDetails.AsQueryable().WhereIf` then it will goes to the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var filters = ListResponse.filter.Where(a => a.FLRefID == EvtID).ToList();
foreach(var tofilter in filters)
{
    if (tofilter == null)
        continue;
    // The value in tofilter can be empty
    bool bFilterID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLEventID);
    bool bFilterText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLText);
    bool bFilterSource = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLSource);
    bool bFilterLevel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLLevel);
    if(new bool[]{bFilterID, bFilterText, bFilterSource, bFilterLevel}.All(z=>!z)) continue // continue when no filters were set like you wanted


    var logs = EventDetails.Where(ax => (bFilterID ? (ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID) : true ) || (bFilterText ? (ax.EventMessage.Contains(tofilter.FLText): true) || (bFilterSource ? (ax.EventSourceName == tofilter.FLSource) : true) || (bFilterLevel ? (ax.Level == tofilter.FLLevel) : true));
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs);
}
```

But for such things its better to use a predicate

Here is an example:

The Predicate builder just a helper to build predicates
Can be found here : [Predicates](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

The for you case you would do the following

```
 var filters = ListResponse.filter.Where(a => a.FLRefID == EvtID).ToList();
    foreach(var tofilter in filters)
    {
        if (tofilter == null)
            continue;
        // The value in tofilter can be empty
        bool bFilterID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLEventID);
        bool bFilterText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLText);
        bool bFilterSource = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLSource);
        bool bFilterLevel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tofilter.FLLevel);
        if(new bool[]{bFilterID, bFilterText, bFilterSource, bFilterLevel}.All(z=>!z)) continue // continue when no filters were set like you wanted

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<EventDetails> ();
if(bFilterID) predicate= predicate.Or(ax => ax.EventID == tofilter.FLEventID);
if(bFilterText) predicate= predicate.Or(ax => ax.EventMessage.Contains(tofilter.FLText));
if(bFilterSource) predicate= predicate.Or(ax => ax.EventSourceName == tofilter.FLSource);
if(bFilterLevel) predicate= predicate.Or(ax => ax.Level == tofilter.FLLevel);

        var logs = EventDetails.Where(predicate.Compile());
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs);
    }
```

Comment: predicate is not bad. I just knew about predicate from your sharing.